# Sorting/Selecting Multiple Tables through One Column

Tags: sql, oracle

My intention for this string of code is simply to be able to have 3 separate tables all being referenced at the same time, but to be able to select specific rows through a single column. Normally this would be easy. However, some of these columns have the same name, depending on the table.

Without joining these tables, how can I select rows with information from one or multiple columns with the same name?

Here is the code thus-far in terms of selecting one column that has a unique name (the names of the tables/columns have been changed for privacy purposes).

```
SELECT * 
FROM  DBASE.APPLE_ORCHARD, 
DBASE.ORANGE_FIELDS, 
DBASE.CHERRY_BUSHES
WHERE ORANGES = '50';
```

And now, what I would supposedly like to do.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  DBASE.APPLE_ORCHARD, 
DBASE.ORANGE_FIELDS, 
DBASE.CHERRY_BUSHES
WHERE WATERING = '100';
```

(the assumption being that each table has their own column named "WATERING")

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer for the purposes of this project

Data-Sample:

```
     Orange_Fields 
COLUMNS -
Oranges
Watering
Insects
Intake

     Apple_Orchard 
COLUMNS -
Apples
Watering
Insects
CO2
Intake

     Cherry_Bushes
COLUMNS -
Cherries
Watering
Insects
Temperature
Intake
```

I have three tables with different columns. Some of the columns have the same name, whereas some of them do not.

How can I sort the information to receive a result such as this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  DBASE.APPLE_ORCHARD, 
    DBASE.ORANGE_FIELDS, 
    DBASE.CHERRY_BUSHES
    WHERE Intake = '50';

Intake   Apples   Oranges   Cherries   Insects
50         32                             4
50         12                             3
50                             52         8
50         16                             12
50                   13                   0
50                             84         2
50                   18                   2
```

The result I am receiving however, looks more like this.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  DBASE.APPLE_ORCHARD, 
    DBASE.ORANGE_FIELDS, 
    DBASE.CHERRY_BUSHES
    WHERE ORANGES = '50';

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Comment: Do a UNION ALL in a derived table. Put conditions in main WHERE clause.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since each table has nothing to relate them with the others, you have to create a separate select statement for each table and then put all your select statements together, I believe this is what @jarlh was referring to, try with something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT  intake, 
                apples, 
                NULL AS oranges,
                NULL AS cherries,
                insects
        FROM  dbase.apple_orchard
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  intake, 
                NULL AS apples, 
                oranges,
                NULL AS cherries,
                insects
        FROM dbase.orange_fields
        UNION ALL
        SELECT intake, 
               NULL AS apples, 
               NULL AS oranges,
               cherries AS cherries,
               insects
        FROM dbase.cherry_bushes
) WHERE intake = '50'
ORDER BY insects;
```